# Admin Post Update Redirection to Posts Screen

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, admin, hooks

Is there a hook I can use that when a post is created or updated it goes back to the list/table page of all the posts. If it is also possible to target a post type as well that would be cracking.

It's a really silly request I know and have argued the toss about it but wanted to make sure it was achievable if not very user friendly.

Steve

Answer (score 8):

Use the `redirect_post_location` filter and [`admin_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) function.

```
add_filter( 'redirect_post_location', 'wpse_124132_redirect_post_location' );
/**
 * Redirect to the edit.php on post save or publish.
 */
function wpse_124132_redirect_post_location( $location ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['save'] ) || isset( $_POST['publish'] ) )
        return admin_url( "edit.php" );

    return $location;
}
```

To redirect to a different url, add everything after the `/wp-admin/` portion of the url. I used `"edit.php"` because the intended url was: `http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/edit.php`.

---

The `redirect_post_location` filter is not documented in the [Codex Filter Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference). You can find it in the `\wp-admin\post.php` file near line 73. This is the WordPress code in the trunk version of WordPress:

```
wp_redirect( apply_filters( 'redirect_post_location', $location, $post_id ) );
```

As you can see, you can also test the `$post_id` redirect based on the `$post_id` or any information obtained from it. To use this second parameter of the filter, you need to pass the *priority* and _accepted_args_ parameters in the [filter call](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter):

```
add_filter( 'redirect_post_location', 'wpse_124132_redirect_post_location', 10, 2 );
```

And update the function parameters:

```
/**
 * Redirect to the edit.php on post save or publish.
 */
function wpse_124132_redirect_post_location( $location, $post_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['save'] ) || isset( $_POST['publish'] ) ) {
        // Maybe test $post_id to find some criteria.
        return admin_url( "edit.php" );
    }

    return $location;
}
```

Comment: Refer to this answer to set up redirection for the custom post type.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23822455/4819200