# Redirect to dashboard user once you click on Publish page

Tags: redirect, dashboard, wp-redirect

Let´s say you are in a creating a page you put the title and the content, the last step is click on "Publish" once you click on publish I want to me redirected to the Dashboard (https://mypage/wp-admin/) of the site where I can see the widgets and the things I can see in the dashboard or other page not to stay in the published page. I found this code but I cant make it work, any Ideas, thank you very much.

```
add_action( ‘save_post’, ‘redirect_user_page_list’, 10, 3 );
function redirect_user_page_list( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
              $user = wp_get_current_user();
              $role = ( array ) $user->roles;
              if ( ‘admin’ == $role[0] ) {
                    $url = "https://mypage.com/wp-admin/index.php";
               wp_redirect($url);
               exit;
              }
        }
}
```

I want to put when the user plublish the post and if the one is administrator.

Thank you very much.

Comment: See if this post from today which is a very similar question helps you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/371644/redirect-to-all-posts-after-post-update-or-publish-in-block-editor

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take a look.